# use implicit differentiation to find the derivative of $(x^2+y^2)^4=6x^2y\,$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, solution-verification, implicit-differentiation

I made up a question to practice implicit differentiation with the relation $(x^2+y^2)^4=6x^2y$. this is my solution:

[image]

Also I am sorry but I don't know how to write the more complex parts of the solution in the question. I would just like to know if I was correct because I do not know how to verify my answer with this type of question, and if anyone has some tips on how to do that it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is correct. And yes, there is a short-cut trick which you can use to verify your answer.

For an implicit equation in $x$ and $y$, put all the terms on left side and assume that to be a function of $x$ and $y$ such that $f(x,y) = 0$.

Now,
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = -\dfrac{f_x}{f_y}$$

Here, $f_x$ and $f_y$ are [partial derivatives](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative) of the function $f$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ respectively.

You can use it directly to save much time.

---

You can also use [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Differentiate+%28x%C2%B2%2By%C2%B2%29%E2%81%B4+%3D+6x%C2%B2y) to check your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct. As far as I know there in now way to verify your answer, you can just re-do the calculations to be sure. If an expression confuse you, you can also write $y$ as  $f(x)$ and use Lagrange's notation $f'(x)$ since you know that you differentiate with respect to $x$.